# I want to know how to calculate percentage difference , month against same month for adjacent years in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco, spotfire-analyst, spotfire-webplayer

I want to  calculate percentage difference ,month against same month for adjacent years in Spotfire. I want to  calculate percentage difference ,month against same month for adjacent years in **Spotfire.** I used different **Percentage** **year over year function** which did not give me desired results.

Previous year balance (April 2022)= 4917789550.01Current year balance (April 2023) = 6936756767.18balance Difference =2,018,967,217.17% balance Difference= balance Difference divided by Previous year x100 Balance.
Which means 2,018,967,217.17 divided by 6936756767.18 x 100 = **41.05%**

But Spotfire is giving me **0.41%**

Kindly assist, I am new to Spotfire

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdAwj.png)

[image]

Comment: is it not just a matter of finding where an extra 100 multiplication or division is?

Comment: please provide a sample data table with your calculation